# Last record by date given a foreign table

Tags: postgresql

Consider this 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE massifs (
id uuid primary key,
name text unique);

CREATE TABLE records (
id uuid primary key,
massif_id uuid  not null references massif(id)
record_date timestamptz not null
some_usefulldata text)
```

I'm trying to get the last result for each `massif`. Something with a subquery ?

For example a result could be

```
massifs.name | record_date::date | some_usefulldata
mont-blanc   | 2020-02-10        | 10
aravis       | 2019-03-10        | 12
```

I think that the question is the same if I add this 2 tables : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html and if I ask this question "give me the last weather records for each cities".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got my Sh** together. Was a bit rusty :

```
SELECT result.* FROM massifs m
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT m.id, m.name, r.record_date, r.some_usefulldata 
    FROM records WHERE (m.id=r.massif_id) 
    ORDER BY r_record_date DESC LIMIT 1
) result ON true
ORDER BY m.id, result.record_date DESC
```

To be honest I found the answer on the timescaledb docs. I thought this was a common problem in TSDB, it was !